# reproduce the plot from image

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing, image

I need to reproduce the gray plot (H4-WT) of below image.Is there any way for doing that in Mathematica?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other colors tend to cover the grey/gray curve.

```
UseImage = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTsCA.png"];
```

Use the color picker to determine that the gray curve has the following color:

```
UseColor = 0.5137254901960784;
UseColor = RGBColor[UseColor, UseColor, UseColor];
```

Then look for the positions of that color in the image:

```
UsePositions = ImageValuePositions[UseImage, UseColor];
```

These are *all* the points we can find that are the color of interest. To ignore the legend, use:

```
UsePositions = Select[UsePositions, (#[[2]] <= 400 &)];
```

Then plot:

```
ListPlot[UsePositions]
```

[image]

Note the missing points. You can filter and then scale these points to match the axes. Then interpolate using a spline or linear model.